# generate number and devided in line for linux

Tags: shell-script, command-line

I want to generate a number between `0001` and `9999` on Linux, separate it into two variables, and print it like this:

```
I will go for  00 and 01
```

I'm using bash on Linux, and looking to generate this output (I assume I could use `seq` or `echo` together maybe?):

**Example**; from number **0001** to **0005** so the result  will be like this:

```
I will go for  00 and 01
I will go for  00 and 02 
I will go for  00 and 03
I will go for  00 and 04 
I will go for  00 and 05
```

Comment: You are editing your post every few seconds so an answer to a particular post will be obsolete quickly. "devided" is not an English word so we'll have to intuit what you mean by that. Can you give an example of the output that you're expecting? Your post is saying you want "I devided 00 and 01", no command that you've tried will give that output.

Comment: This may be an [XY](https://xyproblem.info/) problem but does `for I in {01..05}; do for J in {01..05}; do printf "I devided %s and %s\n" $I $J; done; done` meet your needs?

Comment: Your latest edit says you want to start with `0001` as your input but the output starts with `00`. The number of digits outputted can be worked with but how are you determining both the first number in column 5 and the second number in column 6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the exercise is simply to generate that output:

```bash
seq -w 9999 | sed 's/../something something & and /'
```

This reads the numbers generated by `seq` with `sed` and replaces the first two digits with the text `something something & and`  (where the `&` will be replaced by the two first digits).  The other group of two digits will be untouched and remains at the end of the line.

With `awk`:

```bash
awk 'BEGIN {
    for (i = 0; i <= 99; ++i)
        for (j = 0; j <= 99; ++j) {
          if (i == 0 && j == 0) continue
          printf "something something %.2d and %.2d\n", i, j } }'
```

This uses a double loop to generate all the numbers from `00` to `99` in the inner loop for each number in the outer loop.

The inner `if` statement ensures not to output the result for `00` and `00`.

Comment: There have been 13 edits to the original post so it's not clear to me what the OP is asking. The `bash` command in my comment with two nested loops _might_ be what he's asking for but I'm still uncertain. Does really want 9999*9999 lines of output? More confusion is the text says start at 0000 but the expected output starts at 0001.

Comment: @doneal24 In the current incarnation of the question, the first number is `0001` (split into `00` and `01`), I will fix my answer to adhere to this. I can't find a way of interpreting the question as wanting 9999*9999 lines of output.